# Automatic click on map center when Drawing Manager is active for Markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using `Google Drawing Library` in my application. In this when user click on `Add New Marker` `Button` then i active `Drawing Manager` and user can click anywhere on map to generate a `Marker`and then my following `listener` is execute

```
google.maps.event.addListener(LocationClass.dm, 'markercomplete', function(marker)
{
    LocationClass.markerArray.push(marker);
    marker.set("id", "marker_"+LocationClass.markerArray.length);
    LocationClass.creatEvent();
    LocationClass.dm.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.FALSE);
});
```

Currently user have to click on Button First to activate drawing manager and then click on any point on map for generate marker.
But i want when user click on button drawing manager will activate and automatically add marker in any point (or in center) on map so the same `listener` will execute

So how can i do that?

Here is [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BluAngel/6vVQq/2/) page

Comment: *Now i need that when user click on Add New Marker Button then at the map add marker instead click by user on Map. and after that same listener will execute* - Please translate into English.

Comment: ok i'll do that later thanks @MrUpsidown

Comment: Sorry about that but I really didn't understand it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer:** You can add marker to the center of the map when new marker is added, something like:

```
newMarker:function() {
    LocationClass.dm.setDrawingMode(google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER);

    var centerMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: LocationClass.map,
        position: LocationClass.map.getCenter()
    });
    google.maps.event.trigger(LocationClass.dm, 'markercomplete', centerMarker);
},
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6vVQq/12/).

Comment: No I not want that.
in your example also user have to click on map to generate marker.
I want that DrawingManager auto clicked somehow

Comment: Then correct your question. You wrote *Now i need that when user click on Add New Marker Button then at the center of map add marker instead click by user.*

Comment: Updated answer: center marker is added with click on `Add New Marker` button. And event handler for `markercomplete` is triggered.